# String index out of bounds? (java oracle.jrad.tools.xml.importer.XMLImporter)

Tags: java, oracle, bash

I am getting this error when i try to make script in bash which copy OAF personalization from one serwer to another. Here is my code:

```
java oracle.jrad.tools.xml.importer.XMLImporter /ORACLE/apps/apps_st/comn/html_personal/oracle/apps/eng/changemgmt/webui/customizations/site/0/UserAttributesPG.xml 
-username apps
-password apps
-dbconnection "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST= 172.30.32.222)(PORT=22))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=SRV)))" 
-rootdir ORACLE/apps/apps_st/comn/html_personal/oracle/apps/eng/changemgmt/webui/customizations/site/0/
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are connecting to port 22, which is traditionally [reserved for `ssh`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers). If I connect to that port with a JDBC connection I get the same error stack you showed in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21284242/266304):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 25978
        at java.lang.String.checkBounds(String.java:401)
        at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:338)
        at oracle.net.ns.Packet.extractData(Packet.java:429)
        at oracle.net.ns.RefusePacket.<init>(RefusePacket.java:72)
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:356)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1102)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:320)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:546)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:236)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
        at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleDataSource.java:280)
        at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:207)
        at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:157)
```

Well, slightly different stack because of how I'm connecting and the version I'm using, but the String index is identical. Looks like `ssh` is responding to the connection with more data that the JDBC driver ever expects to see back from a listener.

Changing just the port number to a valid SQL*Net listener port removes this error and the connection succeeds.

So, change to use your listener's actual port number; 1521 by default but you might have something custom. `lsnrctl status` will tell you what it is. It's unlikely to be 22 even if it is customised since that is in the privileged range and the listener would need to be running as `root` to bind to it.

The only reason I can think you might have tried this is because you're tunnelling your SQL*Net connection over `ssh`, to a remote server. If that is the case then you need to use the local port (from a `-L` flag) that maps to the actual listener port on the remote server. So if you had, say, `ssh -L 1234:127.0.0.1:1521 -l user 172.30.32.222`, your `dbconnection` would point to `localhost` and port `1234`. I'm speculating as to why you'd have used 22 though, clearly.